# jquery slider: next button, previous button and pagination object displaying twice when sliding

Tags: php, jquery, css, slider

The following jquery code's next and previous buttons work fine. When the user clicks the next button, the subsequent page's contents slides in contentcolumn div and the same happens for the previous button. However, the contentcolumn displays an extra next, previous button and pagination object. So, now there are 2 next buttons, 2 previous buttons and 2 pagination objects.

How can I get it to display only 1 next button, 1 previous button and 1 pagination object?

FYI, the next button, previous button and pagination object are all outside contentcolumn.My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var pg=1;
$("#contentcolumn:first").show("slide",{'direction':"left"},1000);
$('#next').click(function () {
     if(pg<10){
        pg=pg+1;
        page_str="page="+pg;
        $.get('index2.php',page_str,function(data) {
          $('#contentcolumn').html(data).show("slide

",{'direction':"left"},1000);
             });
            // event.preventDefault();
             //return false;
          };

    });//end $('#next').click

    $('#prev').click(function(){
        if(pg>1){
            pg=pg-1
            page_str="page="+pg;
            $.get('index2.php',page_str,function(data){
                $('#contentcolumn').html(data).show("slide",{'direction':"right"},1000);
            });
        };
    });

});//end document ready
```

style.css

```
   /* CSS Document */
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#topsection{
background-color: #EAEAEA;
height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
/*z-index:0;
*/}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 200px 0 200px; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/
float:left;
}

#leftcolumn{
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of left column*/
margin-right:-200px;
background-color: #C8FC98;
}

#rightcolumn{
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of right column*/
margin-left: -200px; /*Set left marginto -(RightColumnWidth)*/
background-color: #FDE95E;
}

#footer{
clear: left;
width: 100%;
background: black;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}
#footer a{
color: #FFFF80;
}
.mycontent{
margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
margin-top: 0;
}
.innertube{
margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
margin-top: 0;
}


div.pagination {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

    text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
    color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #000099;

        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #000099;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    div.pagination span.disabled {
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        margin: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #EEE;

        color: #DDD;
    }
```

php code:

```
    <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
    <div class="innertube">
    <form type="post">
    <input type="button" id="prev" value="<"  />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentcolumn">
    <div class="innertube">
    <?php
    $pagination='';
    if (function_exists("curl_init")){
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //print_r($data);
        $doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data);
        //$doc=simpleXml_load_file("http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286?format=xml");
        //$doc=simpleXml_load_string($data); 
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);    
        if (!$xml) { 
        echo 'Error while parsing the document'; 
        exit; 
         } 

        //print_r($doc);
        }

        function paginateFunc($xml){
        global $pagination;
        $disp_arr = array();
        $image_array=array();
        // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
            $adjacents =3;

            $items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channel/item');
            $count=count($items);
            $total_pages = $count;

            /* Setup vars for query. */
            $targetpage = "index2.php";     //your file name  (the name of this file)
            $limit = 1;                                 //how many items to show per page
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            echo("page:".$page);
            if($page) 
                $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
            else
                $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0


            /* Setup page vars for display. */
            if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
            $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
            $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
            $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1



            //echo("HALLO");
            foreach ($xml->xpath('//item/content:encoded') as $desc) { 
                preg_match_all('/(?<imgs><img[^>]+>)/m', $desc, $m); 
                /*foreach ($m['imgs'] as $img) { 
                    echo("<img src='".$img."'/>");
                    //array_push(image_array,$img);
                } */
             } 
            // $image_array=$m['imgs'];
          // print_r($image_array);
                     //
            foreach($items as $key => $item){ 
                        //if( ( $key >= $start) && ($key < $start + $limit) ){ 
                            $disp_array[$key]['link']=$item[0]->link;
                            $disp_array[$key]['title']=$item[0]->title;
                            $disp_array[$key]['desc']=$item[0]->description;

            }//end foreach($items 


            foreach($disp_array as $key=>$disp){
                    if($key == $start){

                    //if( ( $key >= $start) && ($key < $start + $limit) ){ 
                        echo("key:".$key." start:".$start);
                        //echo("<div class='mycontent'>");
                         echo("<a href='".$disp_array[$key]['link']."'>".$disp_array[$key]['title']."</a><br>");
                         echo($disp_array[$key]['desc']);
                         //echo(count($m['imgs']));
                         //echo("<img src='".$m['imgs'][$key]."'/>");
                         //echo("</div>");
                      }

            } 
            echo("</div>");//end div innertube
            echo("</div>");//end div contentcolumn
            echo("<div id='rightcolumn'>");
            echo("<div class='innertube'>");
            echo("<form type='post'>");
            echo("<input type='button' id='next' value='>' />");
            echo("</form>");
            echo("</div>");//end div innertube
            echo("</div>");
            echo("<div id='footer'>");
            /* 
                Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
                We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
            */
            //$pagination = "";
            if($lastpage > 1)
            {   
                $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
                //previous button
                if ($page > 1) 
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

                //pages 
                if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                {   
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                }
                elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
                {
                    //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                    if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                    {
                        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                        }
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                    }
                    //in middle; hide some front and some back
                    elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                    {
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                        }
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                    }
                    //close to end; only hide early pages
                    else
                    {
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                        }
                    }
                }

                //next button
                if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
                $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
                }

            }


            if (isset($doc->channel)) paginateFunc($doc);
            ?>
            <?php 

        echo($pagination);
        ?>
        </div><!--closing tag for div footer-->
        </div><!--closing tag for div contentwrapper-->
        </div><!--closing tag for div maincontainer-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the original #next, #previous when you click on 'next' or 'previous' because you are returning those button from html response. Something like

```
$.get('index2.php',page_str,function(data) {
      $('#next').hide();
      $('#previous').hide();
      $('#contentcolumn').html(data).show("slide

",{'direction':"left"},1000);
         });
```

Comment: Ok, i tried Dr. Dan's solution. The original next and previous buttons are hidden now. But the next and previous buttons that slides in as the html response are not working. When i click next or previous it doesn't go to the next or previous page.

Comment: When i click next or previous it doesn't go to the next or previous page. It stays on the same page. When i debugged in chrome, i noticed that the click event is not at all firing. I also tried changing the ids for next and previous buttons to classes ie. .next and .prev. Still the click event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Split the HTML and Ajax calling pages. 
Clear the prev, next link values, before assigning new values.

Comment: i have separated html and ajax calling pages. What do u mean by "clear the prev, next link values before assigning new values"?

Comment: I meant that, move  <input type="button" id="prev" value="<"  /> button in your html page to ajax div ( div that displaying the ajax content). Replace the ajax div with new content and that will not display the earlier buttons.

Answer (score 0):

for those people like me who had wasted many days researching on the net abt jquery sliders.....i finally found this great tutorial for beginners on sliders. Check it out..
http://jc-designs.net/blog/2010/03/jquery-slider-tutorial-for-beginners-how-i-did-mine/comment-page-1/#comment-23934